# rxjs combineLatest emitting in Chrome but not Safari

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I have code, in a component, like this:

```
  constructor(
    public projectS: ProjectService,
    private revenueAnalysis: RevenueAnalysisService,
    public projectYear: ProjectYearService,
  ) {
    this.setupCharts();
    this.projectYear.projectYears$.subscribe(data => console.log('1', data));
    this.revenueAnalysis.revenueAnalysis$.subscribe(data => console.log('2', data));
    this.projectS.project$.subscribe(data => console.log('3', data));

  }

...

setupCharts() {
    combineLatest(
      this.projectYear.projectYears$,
      this.projectS.project$,
      this.revenueAnalysis.revenueAnalysis$
    )
      .subscribe(
        ([projYears, project, _]) => {
          console.log('4 SETUP CHARTS');
          ...
```

In Chrome (macOs) I get expected results: 3, 1, 2, 4 gets logged (in that order)

In Safari (macOs) I get results: 3, 1, 2 gets logged, **but not 4**.

Any clues??

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround

`this.revenueAnalysis.revenueAnalysis$` was previously of type `new ReplaySubject<IRevenueAnalysisR>(1);`

I changed it to `new BehaviorSubject<IRevenueAnalysisR>(null);`, and added some null-checks in the code. All of a sudden it worked.

Doesn't explain why it didn't work with ReplaySubject in all browsers though..